# Why is URLSession not returning data in playground?

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift-playground, urlsession

I cannot understand why this `URLSession` is not working on my playground. The URL works fine using `curl` commands on my terminal, so I know it is active, but I cannot see any list of names printed on my console.

The only print I see is the one "called" after that one, it seems there must be some error, but I have no clue about it, no message. Issue must be around the `URLSession` but cannot get where.

UPDATE

I added an extension to data found on stack, using right after this code

```
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
data.printJson()
```

The data is printed, but still cannot print anything in the for loop, where it should be.

```
extension Data {
           
    func printJson() {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: [])
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
            guard let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("Invalid data")
                return
            }
            print(jsonString)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
import Foundation

//-----------------------------------------------
//MARK: - model
//-----------------------------------------------

struct ResponseRandom: Codable {
    let users: [User]
}

struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    let id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let email: String
    //    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/rationeetsit.png?size=300x300&set=set1"
    let date_of_birth: String//"1958-07-18"
    
}


//-----------------------------------------------
//MARK: - class
//-----------------------------------------------


class HTTPRequest_randomUsers {
    
    //    @Published var users = [UserRandom]()
    
    init() {
        Task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        print("called")
        
        let numberOfItems = 50
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=2&response_type=json") else {
            fatalError("URL error")
        }
        
    
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("not valid response")
                return}
            
            guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("not 200 status")
                return}
            
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
            print("decoded")
            
            await MainActor.run {
                //                    users = decoded.users
                for item in decoded {
                    print(item.first_name)
                }
            }
            
            
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
}

//here my call
let c = HTTPRequest_randomUsers()
```

Comment: This code runs fine on playground.

Comment: let session = URLSession.shared in last we need to call session.resume() may be you forgot to called resume() here

Comment: @loremipsum do you get to print a list of names on console?

Comment: @yogesh-patel I think with async await resume should not be required, how do you think should modify this code?

Comment: Yea, the names print

Comment: such a mystery, I made another playground and a brand new app, cut copied this code and still is not printing anything in both cases. I added an extension where, in a different point, I can print data, but I'm still failing in the for loop. I cannot understand.

Comment: In playground, are you setting `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`?

Comment: There are lots of suggestions we might offer to refine this, but this does work, as is. The problem likely rests in how/when you are invoking it. We need more information to diagnose what your issue is.

Comment: @Rob thanks to your question, I made a bit of search about it and discovered usage of your code and PlaygroundSupport. This solved the playground part of my question! And now, with no change made by me, even the app part is working). Could you give me some hint on how to refine the code? Or post your answer about 'needsIndefiniteExecution' so I can mark as accepted solution.

Comment: Re possible refinements, I might (a) decouple the starting of the request from the instantiation of the web service itself; (b) following standard naming conventions; (c) decode the `dateOfBirth` as a `Date`. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/fc15f98442f1789245e32659d60b91f3 for a few ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network requests run asynchronously (i.e., finish later). But by default, simple Playgrounds will stop when they reach the end of their path of execution. One must tell the Playground to continue execution indefinitely in order for the asynchronous results to be retrieved successfully:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
```

and

```swift
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```